# FB app redirecting outside iframe when callback

Tags: ruby, facebook, sinatra, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am making a app and it's been going ok. When i click a link called "account" it goes to /auth/facebook Great!. Once i have accepted the app/permissions it redirect back to the external side which is on Heroku, also when authenticating a FB logo appears saying Go to Facebook. While doing some research on the FB logo this is due to the FB page being loaded inside the FB iframe so if a can breakout the auth from the iframe in a different window this should sort the issue. On the redirect issue i have set the callback to redirect to my FB app link. The only issue here is if someone clicks on the account 'They wanted to go to the account page' so my work around is stupid as it sends the user back to the index page inside the iframe when i want it to go to the page that had was click inside the iframe i.e account.

If anyone has a idea on this i would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: before if you created i-frame application and redirect use outside I-frame read facebook T&C carefully may be your application got banned

Answer (score 0):

> While doing some research on the FB logo this is due to the FB page being loaded inside the FB iframe so if a can breakout the auth from the iframe in a different window this should sort the issue.

Don’t do an HTTP redirect, but use JavaScript instead:

```
top.location.href = "{URL}";
```

(Btw, this has been discussed multiple times already.)

Comment: I have just found something which is strange but when my app request auth the url says permission.request? etc and another app that actualy works without redirecting out of the iframe, the url say Oauth? but i cant work out why its saying something totally different which seem to be the issue. My guess is the koala gem for facebook which is messing it up. How to sort it is a different matter.

Comment: You can not display the Aouth dialog inside of an iframe, that’s a fact. Maybe the other app you’re talking about is still using an older mechanism of connecting (but by now AFAIK all apps should be using the Aouth dialog v2) – or it’s using JS to ope the dialog in a popup (FB.login) …?